# java Kafka producer error

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I made kafka java producer.
but console said error. kafka server is on aws. and producer is on my mac.
and yet kara server is reachable. When i send message from producer, kafka server shows "Accepted connection .. ".
What is problem?

```
1 [main] INFO kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties - Verifying properties
28 [main] INFO kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties - Property      metadata.broker.list is overridden to xxxxxx:9092
28 [main] INFO kafka.utils.VerifiableProperties - Property serializer.class is overridden to kafka.serializer.StringEncoder
137 [main] INFO kafka.client.ClientUtils$ - Fetching metadata from broker id:0,host: xxxxxx,port:9092 with correlation id 0 for 1 topic(s) Set(words_topic)
189 [main] ERROR kafka.producer.SyncProducer - Producer connection to xxxxxx:9092 unsuccessful
198 [main] WARN kafka.client.ClientUtils$ - Fetching topic metadata with correlation id 0 for topics [Set(words_topic)] from broker [id:0,host: xxxxxx,port:9092] failed
199 [main] ERROR kafka.utils.Utils$ - fetching topic metadata for topics [Set(words_topic)] from broker [ArrayBuffer(id:0,host: xxxxxx,port:9092)] failed
```

And It's kafka console

```
[2015-01-27 05:23:33,767] DEBUG Accepted connection from /xxxxx on /xxxx:9092. sendBufferSize [actual|requested]: [212992|1048576] recvBufferSize [actual|requested]: [212992|1048576] (kafka.network.Acceptor)
[2015-01-27 05:23:33,767] DEBUG Processor 1 listening to new connection from /xxxx:65307 (kafka.network.Processor)
[2015-01-27 05:23:33,872] INFO Closing socket connection to /xxxx. (kafka.network.Processor)
[2015-01-27 05:23:33,873] DEBUG Closing connection from /xxxx:65307 (kafka.network.Processor)
```

This is my code.

```
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("metadata.broker.list", "?????:9092");
    props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
    ProducerConfig config = new ProducerConfig(props);
    Producer<String, String> producer = new Producer<String, String>(config);

    // Now we break each word from the paragraph
        for (String word :
            METAMORPHOSIS_OPENING_PARA.split("\\s")) {
        // Create message to be sent to "words_topic" topic with the word
        KeyedMessage<String, String> data =
                new KeyedMessage<String, String>
                        ("words_topic", word);
        // Send the message
        producer.send(data);
    }
    System.out.println("Produced data");
    // close the producer
    producer.close();

}

// First paragraph from Franz Kafka's Metamorphosis
private static String METAMORPHOSIS_OPENING_PARA =
        "One morning, when Gregor Samsa woke from troubled dreams, "
                + "he found himself transformed in his bed into a horrible "
                + "vermin. He lay on his armour-like back, and if he lifted "
                + "his head a little he could see his brown belly, slightly "
                + "domed and divided by arches into stiff sections.";
```

Comment: are you able to produce messages to the same topic using the console script that shipped with the Kafka distribution

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I solve it

Set  'advertised.host.name' on server.properties of Kafka broker to server's realIP(same to producer's 'metadata.broker.list' property)

refrence : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1092